# Convergence in distribution of $X_1, X_2,... $ to a constant $c$ implies convergence in probability

Tags: probability, proof-verification

[image: proof attempt at convergence in probability]

this is my proof attempt at convergence in probability. Is it right- also if it is right- have we not shown something stronger given we've got the final bit equals 1 and not just tending to 1 so convergence almost surely.

Comment: What you've written in the first box is incorrect. The distributions of $X_n$ approach that limiting distributing at all continuity points of the distribution (i.e., everywhere but $x=c$), but what you've written says that each $X_n=c$ almost surely.

Comment: If you don´t write your proof here in $\LaTeX$ then you should make more effort in an readable upload.

Comment: @kccu I meant tends to instead of =

Comment: @kccu Thank you- in telling me that I now realise at the end why it's convergence in probability and not converence almost surely. You've answered my question

Comment: You seriously need to take a look at [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @probablyme I know how to write Latex - I'm not prepared to do it for a question I just want verified. Admittedly I should write it in neat if I'm not going to write up in pen- apologies for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake end the end as @kccu pointed out was that the last bit was actually a limit- I was supposed to use Algebra of limits to get the first term had limit 1 - minus the second term which had limit 0 so the limit of the total was 1 and I put equality because I foolishly wrote at the start $=$ and not $\rightarrow$.
With that I'm pretty sure this is a valid proof of convergence in probability